# How do I make an array with inputs and then pass it to another function jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have the inputs and button working and it goes to my garage array. I'm supposed to use the newCar function at the bottom of the javascript about where the HTML starts to add the car to the list and put it in an unordered list using jQuery please help I can't get the newCar to work

```
$( document ).ready ( readyNow );

let garage = [];
const maxCars = 3;

function readyNow() {
  console.log( 'JQ' );
  $( '#addCarButton' ).on( 'click', addCar )
} //end readyNow

function addCar() {
  console.log('in addCar');
  //get unser inputs
  //create new object
  let newCars = {
    year: $( '#yearInput' ).val(),
    make: $( '#makeInput' ).val(),
    model: $( '#modelInput' ).val()
  }
  //push the new car into the array
  garage.push( newCars );
  //empty inputs
  if (newCars.year && newCars.make && newCars.model !== '') {
      garage.push(newCars);

      $('#yearInput').val('');
      $('#makeInput').val('');
      $('#modelInput').val('');

      displayGarage(newCars);
    } else {
      console.log('All fields must be filled');
    }
  if (garage.length === 5) {
    $('#yearInput').prop("disabled", true);
    $('#makeInput').prop("disabled", true);
    $('#modelInput').prop("disabled", true);
  }
  console.log(garage);
}

function displayGarage(newCars){
  console.log('in displayGarage');

  $('#garageOut ').append
      ( '<li> Year: ' + newCars.year +
             ' Make: ' + newCars.make +
             ' Model: ' + newCars.model +'</li>');
  }

function required() {
  let empt = document.forms['yearInput']['makeInput']['modelInput'].value;
  if (empt == "")
  {
    console.log('Please enter values in all forms');
    return false;
  }
  else {
    console.log('Car Successfully added!');
    return true;
  }
}
/*
Do not change newCar for base mode!
*/
function newCar(yearInput, makeInput, modelInput){
  console.log('in newCar:', yearInput, makeInput, modelInput);
  const newCarObject = {
    year: yearInput,
    make: makeInput,
    model: modelInput
  }
  garage.push(newCarObject);
  return true;
} // end newCar

//newCar(1991, 'Plymouth', 'Horizon') 
 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="scripts/jQuery.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="scripts/client.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">


  </head>
  <body>

  <h1><img src="images/logo.png" alt="noah's car garage"></h1>

      <h2>Please Enter your Year, Make, and Model: <span id="garageList"></span></h2>
    <input type="string" placeholder="Year" id="yearInput" />
    <input type="string" placeholder="Make" id="makeInput" />
    <input type="string" placeholder="Model" id="modelInput" />
    <button id= "addCarButton">Add Car</button>

    <h3>Garage:</h3>
<div id ="garageOut"></div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and the HTML at the bottom is separated from the javascript file I just couldn't figure out how to make it a separate code thing when I typed out the question

Comment: looks fine to me, but you'd need to run `readyNow` when the html is ready, e.g. add `$(readyNow)`

Comment: how can I get the values of the string when things are inputted and then use the newCar function to display something on html?

Comment: Hi, you can add `onclick` here `<button id="addCarButton" onclick="addCar()">Add Car</button>` so whenever user click on add button your function will get called .

Comment: Not sure I understand you correctly, but right now newCar is not called and addCar is doing everything. You just need to replace the assignment to newCars and other related parts in your addCar function with a call to your newCar function.

Answer (score 0):

You attach the event inside the function `readyNow()`, but that function is never called, so you don't attach the event. You need to call  `$( '#addCarButton' ).on( 'click', addCar )` in the root of your JavaScirpt or inside a selfcalling function. After that it should work.

Another thing, I noticed you are adding the car to the garage two times, after and before  `if (newCars.year && newCars.make && newCars.model !== '')`, I believe you should add the car only once, probably inside the `if` condition, but I'm not a 100 % sure about the bussiness logic, just thought to bring it up to your attention.

[Hope this working example helps](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-firefly-hhyc4?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)!

Comment: im very sorry, I wasnt clear and i forgot a line of code at the top i guess. $( document ).ready ( readyNow ); that is at the top making the readyNow work, and thats making my button work, everything seems to work im really wondering how can i get the value of whats being inputted and use it with the newCar function? ex: year, make model

Comment: It is working correctly for me on the codesandbox I linked. Are you sure your document.ready is triggering correcly?

Answer (score 0):

The `newCar` function itself works. If you want to display the `newCarObject` when you run `newCar` function, you'll need to run `displayGarage` function too, like this

```
function newCar(yearInput, makeInput, modelInput){
  console.log('in newCar:', yearInput, makeInput, modelInput);
  const newCarObject = {
    year: yearInput,
    make: makeInput,
    model: modelInput
  }
  garage.push(newCarObject);
  // Display as unordered list
  displayGarage(newCarObject);
  return true;
} // end newCar
```